# function returning previous value of a list, which is not updated

Tags: python-3.x, function

In my code, there is some pre-written part that is not changeable. when I return a list from the method and in the main function it is not getting the updated list. when I try to print, it prints old list values please help me to return the updated list to the main function

```
class Solution: 
    def func(self,n,p,arr)
        l=arr.copy()
        arr=[]
        for i in range(1,P+1):
           if i in l:
               arr.append(l.count(i))
           else:
               arr.append(0)
        return arr
#The below part is pre-written which is immutable
if __name__=="__main__":
    n=5
    p=5
    arr=[2, 3, 2, 3, 5]
    ob=Solution()
    ob.func(n,p,arr)
    for i in arr:
        print(i)
```

Comment: You need to either do `arr = ob.func(n, p, arr)` (the better approach) or remove `arr = []`. Reassigning a parameter inside a function will never affect the variable that was initially passed in; to get information out of a function you usually have to use `return` inside the function (which you're doing), and assign the returned value to a variable outside the function (which you're not doing).

Comment: I understood what you are saying but the main part is prewritten which I can't change and if I remove arr=[]  the previous elements exist there.

Comment: `arr.clear()` can also be used to remove all elements from `arr` without reassigning it, if necessary - as an alternative to `arr = []`. This will persist because it's _mutation_, not _assignment_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array keeps old values because Python function receive parameter on the basis of object reference pass (the parameter inside function is independent with outside passed variable, but it points to the same memory location).

In your `func()`, arr receives value as a function argument, however, after that you assign the variable arr in func to another object in memory by the statement at line 4.

To achieve your goal, you could replace `arr=[]` (line 4) with `arr.clear()` to keep it pointing to the old memory, thus affecting the contents correspondingly.